# Using SQL Server Management Studio "Script To" Feature via Code

Tags: sql-server, indexing

The Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio has a feature to recreate objects by right-clicking on database objects and generating their "Create Statement" based on their meta information stored in the database.

It is possible to get "Create Statement" String from code?

I would like to connect to one database via python, get the string for creating certain indices and then executing this strings on another database, in order to create equal index structure among different databases.

Comment: Take a look at following solutions based on C#/PowerShell and SMO: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SMO/scriptdatabaseobjectswithsmo/2342/  ; http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/chadmiller/2011/07/25/using-smo-transfer-class-to-script-database-objects/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sp_helpindex by Kimberly Tripp](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/sp_helpindex-v20170228/)
 as the base script and adopt it for your needs. It gets out of system tables **all the information you need to generate** "CREATE INDEX" statements